# Firebase Storage Limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Does anyone know what does exactly mean Uploads & downloads 100,000 each in Firebase Storage transfer limit? It's about downloading or uploading a single file 100000 times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upload a single file 100.000 times or 100.000 files once each. And the same for downloads.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that every single file can be downloaded 100,000 times :(